# Load LinkedList of JavaFX Shapes from YAML file?

Tags: java, javafx, yaml, snakeyaml

I'm attempting to create a Java `LinkedList` from a sequence of JavaFX `Shape` objects stored in a YAML file using the SnakeYAML Java library.

I wrote the following simple Java class for saving & loading `LinkedList` objects to & from YAML files:

```
package com.example.test_1;

import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class YAML
{
    static public LinkedList<Object> YAML_ListLoad()
    {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Load");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("YAML File", "*.yaml"));
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(App.MainStage);

        if (file == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to load YAML file because the entered directory is invalid!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                return YAML_ListRead(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Encountered error while loading YAML file!");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    static public LinkedList<Object> YAML_ListRead(String filePath) throws IOException
    {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);

        return yaml.load(fileReader);
    }

    static public boolean YAML_ListSave(LinkedList<Object> list)
    {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Save");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("YAML File", "*.yaml"));
        fileChooser.setInitialFileName("file.yaml");
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(App.MainStage);

        if (file == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to save YAML file because the entered directory is invalid!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                YAML_ListWrite(file.getAbsolutePath(), list);

                return true;
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Encountered error while saving YAML file!");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    static public void YAML_ListWrite(String filePath, LinkedList<Object> list) throws IOException
    {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath);
        yaml.dump(list, fileWriter);
    }
}
```

Where `YAML_ListLoad` is a function that returns a `LinkedList` of objects it loads from whichever file the user chooses using the `FileChooser`, and `YAML_ListSave` is a function that saves the provided `LinkedList` to a YAML file that the user chooses.

The YAML class above is intended to be ran from the following testing functions:

```
public void Save()
{
    LinkedList<Object> shapes = new LinkedList<Object>();
    shapes.add(new Circle(5, Color.RED));
    shapes.add(new Circle(10, Color.BLUE));

    YAML.YAML_ListSave(shapes);
}

public void Load()
{
    LinkedList<Object> shapes = YAML.YAML_ListLoad();

    System.out.println(shapes);
}
```

Where `Save` simply creates 2 JavaFX `Circle` objects, and attempts to save them in a YAML file, and `Load` simply tries to load a YAML file into a `LinkedList`.

In the code above, the saving functions appear to work well. Running the `Save` function in the runner excerpt above results in the following YAML file being created:

```
- !!javafx.scene.shape.Circle
  accessibleHelp: null
  accessibleRole: NODE
  accessibleRoleDescription: null
  accessibleText: null
  blendMode: null
  cache: false
  cacheHint: DEFAULT
  centerX: 0.0
  centerY: 0.0
  clip: null
  cursor: null
  depthTest: INHERIT
  disable: false
  effect: null
  eventDispatcher: !!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher {}
  fill: !!javafx.scene.paint.Color {}
  focusTraversable: false
  id: null
  inputMethodRequests: null
  layoutX: 0.0
  layoutY: 0.0
  managed: true
  mouseTransparent: false
  nodeOrientation: INHERIT
  onContextMenuRequested: null
  onDragDetected: null
  onDragDone: null
  onDragDropped: null
  onDragEntered: null
  onDragExited: null
  onDragOver: null
  onInputMethodTextChanged: null
  onKeyPressed: null
  onKeyReleased: null
  onKeyTyped: null
  onMouseClicked: null
  onMouseDragEntered: null
  onMouseDragExited: null
  onMouseDragOver: null
  onMouseDragReleased: null
  onMouseDragged: null
  onMouseEntered: null
  onMouseExited: null
  onMouseMoved: null
  onMousePressed: null
  onMouseReleased: null
  onRotate: null
  onRotationFinished: null
  onRotationStarted: null
  onScroll: null
  onScrollFinished: null
  onScrollStarted: null
  onSwipeDown: null
  onSwipeLeft: null
  onSwipeRight: null
  onSwipeUp: null
  onTouchMoved: null
  onTouchPressed: null
  onTouchReleased: null
  onTouchStationary: null
  onZoom: null
  onZoomFinished: null
  onZoomStarted: null
  opacity: 1.0
  pickOnBounds: false
  radius: 5.0
  rotate: 0.0
  rotationAxis: &id001 {}
  scaleX: 1.0
  scaleY: 1.0
  scaleZ: 1.0
  smooth: true
  stroke: null
  strokeDashOffset: 0.0
  strokeLineCap: SQUARE
  strokeLineJoin: MITER
  strokeMiterLimit: 10.0
  strokeType: CENTERED
  strokeWidth: 1.0
  style: ''
  translateX: 0.0
  translateY: 0.0
  translateZ: 0.0
  userData: null
  viewOrder: 0.0
  visible: true
- !!javafx.scene.shape.Circle
  accessibleHelp: null
  accessibleRole: NODE
  accessibleRoleDescription: null
  accessibleText: null
  blendMode: null
  cache: false
  cacheHint: DEFAULT
  centerX: 0.0
  centerY: 0.0
  clip: null
  cursor: null
  depthTest: INHERIT
  disable: false
  effect: null
  eventDispatcher: !!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher {}
  fill: !!javafx.scene.paint.Color {}
  focusTraversable: false
  id: null
  inputMethodRequests: null
  layoutX: 0.0
  layoutY: 0.0
  managed: true
  mouseTransparent: false
  nodeOrientation: INHERIT
  onContextMenuRequested: null
  onDragDetected: null
  onDragDone: null
  onDragDropped: null
  onDragEntered: null
  onDragExited: null
  onDragOver: null
  onInputMethodTextChanged: null
  onKeyPressed: null
  onKeyReleased: null
  onKeyTyped: null
  onMouseClicked: null
  onMouseDragEntered: null
  onMouseDragExited: null
  onMouseDragOver: null
  onMouseDragReleased: null
  onMouseDragged: null
  onMouseEntered: null
  onMouseExited: null
  onMouseMoved: null
  onMousePressed: null
  onMouseReleased: null
  onRotate: null
  onRotationFinished: null
  onRotationStarted: null
  onScroll: null
  onScrollFinished: null
  onScrollStarted: null
  onSwipeDown: null
  onSwipeLeft: null
  onSwipeRight: null
  onSwipeUp: null
  onTouchMoved: null
  onTouchPressed: null
  onTouchReleased: null
  onTouchStationary: null
  onZoom: null
  onZoomFinished: null
  onZoomStarted: null
  opacity: 1.0
  pickOnBounds: false
  radius: 10.0
  rotate: 0.0
  rotationAxis: *id001
  scaleX: 1.0
  scaleY: 1.0
  scaleZ: 1.0
  smooth: true
  stroke: null
  strokeDashOffset: 0.0
  strokeLineCap: SQUARE
  strokeLineJoin: MITER
  strokeMiterLimit: 10.0
  strokeType: CENTERED
  strokeWidth: 1.0
  style: ''
  translateX: 0.0
  translateY: 0.0
  translateZ: 0.0
  userData: null
  viewOrder: 0.0
  visible: true
```

However, attempting to load that created YAML file back into a `LinkedList` by calling `Save` results in many errors, including:

```
Caused by: Cannot create property=eventDispatcher for JavaBean=Circle[centerX=0.0, centerY=0.0, radius=0.0, fill=0x000000ff]
 in 'reader', line 1, column 3:
    - !!javafx.scene.shape.Circle
      ^
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher; exception=java.lang.InstantiationException: NoSuchMethodException:com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher.<init>()
 in 'reader', line 16, column 20:
      eventDispatcher: !!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEvent ... 
                       ^

 in 'reader', line 16, column 20:
      eventDispatcher: !!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEvent ... 
                       ^

Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher; exception=java.lang.InstantiationException: NoSuchMethodException:com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher.<init>()
 in 'reader', line 16, column 20:
      eventDispatcher: !!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEvent ... 
                       ^
```

It would appear to me that the entries marked by `!!` in the YAML file are treated as some sort of `null` or empty entries. It appears that the YAML parser isn't able to parse those.

What would be the proper way of loading a sequence of JavaFX `Shape` objects from a YAML file? Is it even possible to load JavaFX objects using SnakeYAML?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Directly persisting a UI object is probably not a good approach. (Exceptions to this might include writing a GUI builder, like SceneBuilder, but even then there are probably better approaches). The problem is that UI objects have a lot of properties, many of which you almost certainly don't want to persist. For example, it really doesn't make sense to persist any event handlers. The errors you're getting arise from trying to recreate internal properties that are represented by classes that are not part of the public API (`com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEvent`, for example).

Comment: A better approach is probably to create a model for your application (using a MVC, MVP, or MVVM type of approach). What do the circles actually represent in terms of data in your application? Write classes that represent just the data. Then persist the model instead of the UI and reconstruct the UI from the model you load from the file.

Comment: I don't know SnakeYAML so it may have ways you can specify what to persist, but this still feels like the wrong approach.

Comment: What's appearing to happen is that every entry with `!!` present appears to fail to parse. What is the meaning of the `!!` designation in YAML? Does that indicate an invalid entry?

Comment: No, the file is being parsed just fine. The errors are that certain classes, such as `NodeEventDispatcher`, do not have no-argument constructors, so the library doesn't know how to construct them. Maybe SnakeYAML can be configured to work with missing no-argument constructors, I'm not sure. But as explained by James, you should not be directly serializing UI objects in the first place; there are other issues beyond the missing no-argument constructors. Create a model class that only contains the data you need persisted, then save and load objects of that class, not the UI objects.

Comment: From the snippet you posted, the `!!` just seems to precede a class name (as opposed to a property name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of serializing and deserializing shapes based on a YAML file format.

It uses [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to assist with the marshaling operations.  Jackson (currently) uses SnakeYAML as its YAML implementation, though that is completely transparent to the usage via the Jackson API.

It only allows a single shape type (a `Circle`) but could be extended to handle other shapes without much difficulty.

**App Output**

[image: screenshot]

```
Wrote: /var/folders/87/r96kpgbj5tjdpsgml9gb_g8c0000gn/T/shapes-4277733445362494936.yaml
---
- !<Circle>
  centerX: 40.0
  centerY: 50.0
  radius: 20.0
  fill: "BLUE"
- !<Circle>
  centerX: 20.0
  centerY: 20.0
  radius: 10.0
  fill: "RED"

Read: /var/folders/87/r96kpgbj5tjdpsgml9gb_g8c0000gn/T/shapes-4277733445362494936.yaml
[CircleModel[centerX=40.0, centerY=50.0, radius=20.0, fill=BLUE], CircleModel[centerX=20.0, centerY=20.0, radius=10.0, fill=RED]]
```

**Alternate implementation using FXML**

You could store the objects as FXML, then you can load them using the [`FXMLLoader`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html).

That may work well if you have some tool to create the shapes and export them in FXML format.

However, if you need to create an FXML file programmatically from model objects in your application, that might be a little difficult. I know of no easily available 3rd party library to do that.  Jackson, similar to that used here for YAML, could create basic FXML files with a bit of additional programming.  However, that is outside the scope of this answer.

**Using an alternate data format (JSON or XML)**

To use JSON as a serialization format, in the `ShapeRepository` class, use:

```
private final JsonFactory serializationFactory = new JsonFactory();
```

instead of the `YamlFactory`:

```
private final JsonFactory serializationFactory = new YAMLFactory();
```

Similarly for XML, see:

- [XML Serialization and Deserialization with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization).

**App Code**

*module-info.java*

```
module com.example.persistentcirclesapp {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

    exports com.example.persistentcirclesapp;
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PersistentCirclesApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PersistentCirclesApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>21.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*ShapeApplication.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ShapeApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        ShapeRepository shapeRepository = new ShapeRepository();
        shapeRepository.save(
                List.of(
                        new CircleModel(40, 50, 20, "BLUE"),
                        new CircleModel(20, 20, 10, "RED")
                )
        );

        List<ShapeModel> shapes = shapeRepository.load();

        ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        stage.setScene(new Scene(shapeRenderer.render(shapes)));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*ShapeModel.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CircleModel.class, name = "Circle")
})
public sealed interface ShapeModel permits CircleModel {}
```

*CircleModel.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

public record CircleModel(
        double centerX,
        double centerY,
        double radius,
        String fill
) implements ShapeModel {}
```

*ShapeRepository.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

public class ShapeRepository {
    private final Path shapeRepositoryPath;

    private final JsonFactory serializationFactory = new YAMLFactory();
    private final ObjectMapper mapper =
            new ObjectMapper(serializationFactory);

    private final CollectionType shapeCollectionType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
            List.class, ShapeModel.class
    );

    private final ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper(serializationFactory)
            .writerFor(shapeCollectionType);

    private final ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper(serializationFactory)
            .readerFor(shapeCollectionType);

    public ShapeRepository() throws IOException {
        shapeRepositoryPath = Files.createTempFile("shapes-", ".yaml");
    }

    public ShapeRepository(Path shapeRepositoryPath) {
        this.shapeRepositoryPath = shapeRepositoryPath;
    }

    public void save(List<ShapeModel> shapes) throws IOException {
        writer.writeValue(
                shapeRepositoryPath.toFile(),
                shapes
        );

        System.out.println("Wrote: " + shapeRepositoryPath + "\n" + Files.readString(shapeRepositoryPath));
    }

    public List<ShapeModel> load() throws IOException {
        List<ShapeModel> shapes = reader.readValue(
                shapeRepositoryPath.toFile()
        );

        System.out.println("Read: " + shapeRepositoryPath + "\n" + shapes);

        return shapes;
    }
}
```

*ShapeRenderer.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.util.List;

public class ShapeRenderer {
    private final ShapeFactory shapeFactory = new ShapeFactory();

    public Pane render(List<ShapeModel> shapes) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        shapes.stream()
                .map(shapeFactory::createShape)
                .forEach(shape ->
                        pane.getChildren().add(shape)
                );

        return pane;
    }
}
```

*ShapeFactory.java*

```
package com.example.persistentcirclesapp;

import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public class ShapeFactory {
    public Shape createShape(ShapeModel shapeModel) {
        return switch(shapeModel) {
            case CircleModel circleModel ->
                    new Circle(
                            circleModel.centerX(),
                            circleModel.centerY(),
                            circleModel.radius(),
                            Paint.valueOf(circleModel.fill())
                    );
        };
    }
    
    public ShapeModel createModel(Shape shape) {
        return switch(shape) {
            case Circle circle ->
                    new CircleModel(
                            circle.getCenterX(), 
                            circle.getCenterY(), 
                            circle.getRadius(), 
                            circle.getFill().toString() 
                    );
            default -> 
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported shape type " + shape.getClass().getName());
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As [explained in the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-javabeans),

> If the custom Java class conforms to the `JavaBean` specification it can be loaded and dumped without any extra code.

The class `com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher` does not conform to the `JavaBean` specification since it does not provide a zero-argument constructor. This is what the error messages are trying to tell you.

You can [write a custom Constructor](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers) to work around this limitation, but as others have said, directly storing UI classes is not a good approach – generally, automatic serialization is viable for passive data classes, but not generally for any Java class.

Concerning `!!`, these are simply *tags* that are applied to the following node. `!!javafx.scene.shape.Circle` is applied to the following mapping containing all the succeeding key-value pairs, while `!!com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher` is applied to the following empty mapping `{}`. The mapping is empty because the class does not have any public properties (values that are either public or have getters & setters).

Tags help SnakeYAML determine which class it should load some mapping into. They are required when the actual object's class does not equal the defined static class of the property. For example, `eventDispatcher` is defined to be a `javafx.event.EventDispatcher` but the actual value in the object you serialize is a `com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeEventDispatcher`. SnakeYAML thus adds the tag so that it knows when loading that it needs to construct this derived class. (And then it doesn't work because that class is not a `JavaBean`.)