# Node Cloning in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, cloning

I have a JavaFX `Node` object, and I wish to clone it via code.

It's my understanding that Java variables are reference-types, and simply doing something like `clonedNode = oldNode` would result in `clonedNode` pointing to `oldNode`.

It doesn't appear that JavaFX has an in-built function for cloning `Node` objects. Hence, I attempted to write a cloning function myself as such (suppose I'm only working with `Node`s of types `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Polygon`, `Line`, `Text` and `Group`, and that I only care about the `Fill`, `Stroke`, `Text` and positional properties of the `Node`):

```
public static Node NodeClone(Node oldNode)
{
    Node clonedNode = null;

    if (oldNode.getClass() == Circle.class)
    {
        Circle oldCircle = (Circle)oldNode;

        Circle clonedCircle = new Circle();
        clonedCircle.setRadius(oldCircle.getRadius());
        clonedCircle.setFill(oldCircle.getFill());
        clonedCircle.setStroke(oldCircle.getStroke());
        clonedCircle.setStrokeWidth(oldCircle.getStrokeWidth());

        clonedNode = clonedCircle;
    }
    else if (oldNode.getClass() == Rectangle.class)
    {
        Rectangle oldRectangle = (Rectangle)oldNode;

        Rectangle clonedRectangle = new Rectangle();
        clonedRectangle.setWidth(oldRectangle.getWidth());
        clonedRectangle.setHeight(oldRectangle.getHeight());
        clonedRectangle.setFill(oldRectangle.getFill());
        clonedRectangle.setStroke(oldRectangle.getStroke());
        clonedRectangle.setStrokeWidth(oldRectangle.getStrokeWidth());

        clonedNode = clonedRectangle;
    }
    else if (oldNode.getClass() == Polygon.class)
    {
        Polygon oldTriangle = (Polygon)oldNode;

        Polygon clonedTriangle = new Polygon();
        LinkedList<Double> clonedPoints = new LinkedList<Double>(oldTriangle.getPoints());
        clonedTriangle.getPoints().setAll(clonedPoints);
        clonedTriangle.setFill(oldTriangle.getFill());
        clonedTriangle.setStroke(oldTriangle.getStroke());
        clonedTriangle.setStrokeWidth(oldTriangle.getStrokeWidth());

        clonedNode = clonedTriangle;
    }
    else if (oldNode.getClass() == Line.class)
    {
        Line oldLine = (Line)oldNode;

        Line clonedLine = new Line();
        clonedLine.setStartX(oldLine.getStartX());
        clonedLine.setStartY(oldLine.getStartY());
        clonedLine.setEndX(oldLine.getEndX());
        clonedLine.setEndY(oldLine.getEndY());
        clonedLine.setStroke(oldLine.getStroke());
        clonedLine.setStrokeWidth(oldLine.getStrokeWidth());

        clonedNode = clonedLine;
    }
    else if (oldNode.getClass() == Text.class)
    {
        Text oldText = (Text)oldNode;

        Text clonedText = new Text();
        clonedText.setFont(oldText.getFont());
        clonedText.setText(oldText.getText());
        clonedText.setFill(oldText.getFill());

        clonedNode = clonedText;
    }
    else if (oldNode.getClass() == Group.class)
    {
        Group oldGroup = (Group)oldNode;

        Group clonedGroup = new Group();

        for (int i = 0; i < oldGroup.getChildren().size(); i++)
            clonedGroup.getChildren().add(NodeClone(oldGroup.getChildren().get(i)));

        clonedNode = clonedGroup;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new java.lang.Error("ERROR: Attempting to clone an unrecognized JavaFX oldNode type!");
    }

    clonedNode.setTranslateX(oldNode.getTranslateX());
    clonedNode.setTranslateY(oldNode.getTranslateY());
    clonedNode.setLayoutX(oldNode.getLayoutX());
    clonedNode.setLayoutY(oldNode.getLayoutY());
    clonedNode.setRotate(oldNode.getRotate());

    return clonedNode;
}
```

With the function above returning a cloned instance of the provided `Node` object.

My question is, will calling the various `Node`'s property setters directly on the results of the property getters result in the property values be passed by value or by reference?

In other words, will the properties of the cloned `Node` returned by the function above be truly unique or still point to the original `Node`'s properties?

From my own testing, this function appears to indeed produce fully unique `Node`s, but I wanted to verify before fully comitting to this `Node` cloning approach.

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, your code correctly makes copies of Nodes and their properties. However, there are [many more properties of Node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#property-summary), and of course, there are many subclasses of Node in addition to shapes and Group.  Is that a concern for you?  Or do you only care about those properties, and do you know for certain that the Node argument will always be a shape or Group?

Comment: *"will the properties of the cloned Node returned by the function above be truly unique or still point to the original Node's properties?"*. It depends on the type of the property (though in this case it doesn't really matter). If the property is a primitive type (e.g. `double`, which is the case with `width`, `height`, `radius`, etc), your new node will get a copy of the *value*. If the property has a reference type (e.g. `fill` and `stroke` have type `Paint`) then your new node gets a copy of the reference (i.e. both nodes refer to the same `Paint` instance)...

Comment: However, since `Paint` (and most value types in JavaFX) is immutable, it doesn't matter if your nodes share the same instance. You can't change any properties of that instance anyway.

Comment: All that said, dong this is something of an indication of a bad design. Your nodes represent (are views of) some application state that you're trying to display. You should consider creating classes that represent the application state independently of the view, and then creating views that update when the state changes. Then the functionality where you create new objects is delegates to the application state level, not the view level.

Comment: You may be interested in the similar code (class `ShapeFactory`) in this [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77377572/1155209).  That linked answer uses a model, but the domain it is modeling is shapes, so it is a model of shapes.  In another domain, you might model objects of the domain rather than shapes.

Comment: For questions like this, it is usually best to provide context as to what you actually want to achieve (high-level goal).  Cloning nodes might not be the appropriate solution for the goal, as pointed out by James_D.  This may be an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info).  Context can also help make the answers to questions like VGR's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

"My question is, will calling the various Node's property setters directly on the results of the property getters result in the property values be passed by value or by reference?"

**Answer:**

There is no "pass by references" in Java. In Java, everything is passed by value. If you pass a reference (like Cat cat), the reference is passed by value too.

If you have `public void abc(Cat cat)`, the reference of cat is passed by value and the method creates its own copy of the passed value (which is the reference of cat) inside of itself.

If you execute a Setter of the copied reference inside your method, you are editing the one and only cat in your RAM.

Think of it like this:

1. There is a paper with an address written on it. That's the reference.
2. The house at the address is the value behind the reference.
3. A copy of the paper points to the exact same house.